# Updating wordpress form via AJAX does not work the second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

I have built a theme options page in wordpress using settings api. I want to update the forms on the page using ajax. They seem to be working fine the first time, but when I click "submit" again without refreshing the page, the whole page just gives me a "0".
Please note that since i am handling errors and validation using wordpress native, the whole form is reloaded using AJAX. I know this is weird since the form that triggers the ajax request itself is reloaded. Let me know if there is a workaround for this. Here is the code

```
$cg("#cgform").submit(function(){
    var b = $cg(this).serialize();
    var cgdata =  { action : "cg_options_save", cgnonce: cgform.cgnonce ,data: b };
    cg_ajax_request(cgdata,cg_form_callback);  
    return false;
});

//Ajax request
function cg_ajax_request(data,fcall){
    $cg.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {fcall(response);}); 
}
```

The cg_ajax_callback function populated the received form inside a div.

Please let me know the "correct" way to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the event handler is bound to the form which is reloaded by the ajax call. The second time you try to submit the form it's actually the new instance that was inserted by the first ajax call, which doesn't have an event handler attached to it. Use the `on` method to bind the event handler instead, this will dynamically bind the event handler to the new form when it's inserted.

```
$cg(document).on('submit', "#cgform", function(){
    var b = $cg(this).serialize();
    var cgdata =  { action : "cg_options_save", cgnonce: cgform.cgnonce ,data: b };
    cg_ajax_request(cgdata,cg_form_callback);  
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but now its not working on even the first time. Your explanation makes sense, but the solution seems to be not working

Comment: Try the updated version. The `$cg` looked like a jquery object to me but I'm guessing that's your override for the global jquery object?

Comment: Yes its the override
`jQuery(document).ready(function($cg)`
and this update is also not working :(
I was reading the online documention of .on() [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and they have not used it the way you have. But their way is also not working

Comment: When you say it's not working, what actually happens? Does the form submit the first time using the `on` method? Have you inspected the HTML of the form that is inserted by the ajax request? Is it's `id` attribute actually set to `cgform`?

Comment: Forget what I wrote before. I did not do a preventDefault to stop the form action from bubbling up. stupid me. you method works like a charm after the inclusion of `document`. Can you explain me why we needed to add this? And also is this a good way to ajaxify my form? I am thinking in terms of security and speed

Comment: The `on` method is necessary in this case because it binds the event handler to an element other than the form, because the form is added dynamically. Using `on` is the preferred way to bind events to elements dynamically, the `live`, `delegate` and `bind` actually all delegate to `on`.  Look at [this article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html) for a good explanation.